# how to write a common component to include all validation message in angular5?

Tags: angular5

I have a project build with angular5, and there are lots of repetition of input component like:

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
       required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
       [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
     class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>
</div>
```

The component should input FormControl, when the it touched, show error.
Is there any method to write it as a shared component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your shared module create a ValidationErrorComponent:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'validation-error',
      templateUrl: 'validation-error.component.html'
    })
    export class ValidationErrorComponent implements OnInit {


      @Input('control')
      public control: AbstractControl;

      constructor() {

      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        if (!this.control) {
          this.control = new FormControl();
        }
      }
    }
```

Then in the validation-error.component.html

```
<div class="help-block" *ngIf="control?.touched">
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">Field is required</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('email')">The email is invalid</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('min')">The value is too small</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('max')">The value is too large</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('minlength')">The field is too short</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('maxlength')">Maximum of 35 characters</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('commaError')">Comma should not contained</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('customError')">This field should only contains letters/numbers and / . # -.</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('numberLetterOnlyError')">This field should only contains letters and numbers</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('numberLetterSpace')">This field should only contains letters/numbers/spaces </span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('customError')">This field should only contains only letters/numbers and / .  # - </span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('matchOther')">The repeat password is not match.</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError('clearingCodeRequiredError')">clearingCodeRequiredError Error</span>
</div>
```

Noted that errors like clearingCodeRequiredError are your custom error.

At last you can you use it by import the shared module, and in your component html code:

```
 <section class="col col-6">
                                            <label class="input">
                                                Name
                                                <span style="color: red">*</span>
                                                <input type="text"
                                                       formControlName="name"
                                                       [(ngModel)]="pricingPlan.name"
                                                       name="name"
                                                       placeholder="">
                                                <validation-error
                                                        [control]="myForm.get('name')"></validation-error>
                                            </label>
                                        </section>
```

Hope it can help!